# R: Retrieve value of previous row in a column without a for loop

Tags: r, loops, indexing

I am trying to retrieve the value of the previous row of the same column. At the moment, I managed to access it through a for loop using [i-1]:

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(x))) {
    x$w_ratio[i] <- (x$cum_liquidity[i-1]*x$w_ratio[i-1] + x$liquidity[i]*x$ratio[i]) / x$cum_liquidity[i]
```

Is there a function to retrieve the value of the previous row of the same column without the for loop? This would be way more efficient from a computational perspective. Thanks!

Comment: What about lag(column_of_interest,1)?

Comment: The lag function does not seem to work with a row index

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this would be to use the `lag()` function as part of a call to mutate using the `dplyr` library and dataframe `x`.

```r
x %>%
  mutate(
    w_ratio = (lag(cum_liquidity) * lag(w_ratio) - liquidity * ratio) / liquidity
  )
```

Comment: This solution does not seem to work as it does not allow for iterations. Basically, w_ratio should be updated iteratively. Do you know how this could be implemented with another solution or with base R, for instance, through the Reduce() function?

Comment: Apologies I had assumed that you wanted only the previous values rather than the accumulated previous values. I will try and write a call to reduce function to acheive this.

Comment: No problems and thanks, please let me know if you need a reproducible example.

Comment: dat <- data.frame(liquidity=c(1,2,3,4,-1,5,6,-2,7),
                  ratio=c(0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,-0.3,0.4,0.3,-0.3,0.4),
                  type=c("Mint","Mint","Mint","Mint","Burn","Mint","Mint","Burn","Mint"))

dat$cum_liquidity <- cumsum(dat$liquidity)

dat$w_ratio <- 0
dat$w_ratio[1] <- dat$ratio[1]

for (i in 2:(nrow(dat))) {
  if (dat$type[i] == "Mint") {
    dat$w_ratio[i] <- (dat$cum_liquidity[i-1]*dat$w_ratio[i-1] + dat$liquidity[i]*dat$ratio[i]) / dat$cum_liquidity[i]
    } else {
      dat$w_ratio[i] <- dat$w_ratio[i-1]
    }
}